# What programming language uses #s for placeholders?

Tags: string, programming-languages, escaping, printf, string-formatting

In C, you can write stuff like `printf("Hello %s, how are you?\n", name)`.

What programming language uses `#s` instead of `%s` for that purpose?

Comment: Nothing interesting comes up at http://codesearch.google.com/#search/&q=%5C%20%23s%5C%20&sq=&type=cs, except for the C preprocessor `#var` to stringify a macro argument.

Answer (score 1):

You may be thinking of Ruby, which uses `#{..}` for string interpolation.

```ruby
foo = 42
puts "Hello #{foo}"       # this prints "Hello 42"
```